# Remove text from string PowerShell

Tags: string, powershell, replace

I´m vacation hangover and cannot wrap my head around an Powershell dilemma!

I´ve a script where I get the following output below which is saved to a variable `$ScanOutput`. Now I want to filter out and only keep the code after `ExitCode=` (Can be 500 or 0). How can I filter out everything before and after `500` (which can be other codes, not static).

```
@{StdOut=Checking for updates...
Determining available updates...
Check for updates completed
Number of applicable updates for the current system configuration: 0
No updates available.
Execution completed.
Program exited with return code: 500
; ExitCode=500; StdErr=}
```

Thanks in advance! Kind regards,
JN

Comment: I believe there should be an regex option while replacing...then you can try with that.Let us know if you need help with regex

Comment: Its a hash table, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables?view=powershell-7

Comment: @DanielBjörk is correct. `$ScanOutput` is **not** a string, but an object with properties. You are just looking at the stringified representation of that object. To get the value of the `ExitCode` property, simply do `$ScanOutput.ExitCode`

Comment: If `$ScanOutput` is a string, then something unnecessary has happened for it to be so. It seems like there was a perfectly good custom object that was cast to string or surrounded in double quotes. If you reverse whatever that was, then `$ScanOutput.ExitCode` will work, which is the more *PowerShelly* solution.

Comment: @AdminOfThings After a little bit of testing now it´s no longer a string. I must have messed up someting...
Now after running $ScanOutput.GetType(), I see it´s a PSCustomObject. Therefor I can run $ScanOutput.ExitCode as AdminOfThings wrote

Comment: @DanielBjörk You where correct all along. If you do things the right way then you usally get the correct data... Thanks for the help!

Comment: @JNilsson That is really great to hear. I will add back my answer even though you cannot accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use `Select-String` :

```
($ScanOutput | Select-String -Pattern 'ExitCode=(\d+)').Matches.Groups[1].Value
500
```

Comment: Thank you! The ExitCode can either be 500 or 0. Can I add Matches.Groups[1].Value 500 or 0?

Comment: Think I found the answer myself. Test before sending another question ;)
$ExitCode = ($ScanOutput | Select-String -Pattern 'ExitCode=(\d+)').Matches.Groups[1].Value

Gives me the code, as you wrote!

Comment: no point adding that detail because presumably you'll be checking the value later on? Although you could wrap an `If` statement around the whole thing - `If ( ($ScanOutput | Select-String -Pattern 'ExitCode=(\d+)').Matches.Groups[1].Value -eq 500 ) { Do-Something } Else { Do-somethingelse } `

Comment: @Trix, Yeah agreed! $ExitCode is pretty useless!

Answer (score 0):

Many ways to skin a cat, assuming the delimiter `;` is consistently placed. Might be nice to test which method is fastest:

```
($scanoutput -split ';')[1].Trim()
ExitCode=500
```

Comment: The desired output seems to be only `500` and not `ExitCode=500`

Comment: Yes, I noticed that a bit late, which is why your solution is better

Comment: yes, it LOOKS like a hashtable. - but who knows, it could be a horrible string. But if it is in fact a hashtable, I totally agree, just work directly with the value. Should have pointed that out myself.

Comment: @Trix Well he actually said it was not a string in his response to my comment when i said its a hash table.

Comment: @DanielBjörk Cannot find my respons to you. But it´s a String as mentioned in the title of the question. I´m sorry if my question was unclear, will try to be more informative in future questions!

Answer (score 0):

Since JNilsson came back and said that I actually was correct in my statement that it was hash table I will add back my answer to help others with similar problem.

The object

```
@{StdOut=Checking for updates... Determining available updates... Check for updates completed Number of applicable updates for the current system configuration: 0 No updates available. Execution completed. Program exited with return code: 500 ; ExitCode=500; StdErr=}
```

To get the ExitCode from the object simply make sure to assign it to a variable, in my case $hash then you can get the value by doing this:

```
$hash.ExitCode
```